# Refactor this method to reduce its Cognitive Complexity from 19 to the 15 allowed. How to refactor this code

Tags: javascript, angular, sonarqube, karma-jasmine, sonarlint

How to reduce the complexity of the given piece of code? I am getting this error in Sonarqube---> Refactor this method to reduce its Cognitive Complexity from 19 to the 15 allowed.

Here the daysPassed is the time which is in the form of minutes

```
        let output = "";
        if (daysPassed < 60) {
          output = this.formatOutput(daysPassed, "min");
        } else if (daysPassed < 60 * 24) {
          output = this.formatOutput(Math.floor(daysPassed / 60), "hour");
        } else if (daysPassed < 60 * 24 * 30) {
          output = this.formatOutput(Math.floor(daysPassed / (60 * 24)), "day");
        } else {
          output = this.formatOutput(Math.floor(daysPassed / (60 * 24 * 30)), "month");
        }
       

        formatOutput(value, unit) {
           return `${value} ${unit}${value === 1 ? '' : 's'} ago`;
        }
```

I tried like : this also not working

```
        let output = "";
        if (daysPassed < 60) {
          output = `${Math.floor(daysPassed)} mins ago`;
        } else if (daysPassed < 60 * 24) {
          output = `${Math.floor(daysPassed / 60)} hours ago`;
        } else {
          const timeUnits = [
            { unit: "day", duration: 60 * 24 },
            { unit: "month", duration: 60 * 24 * 30 }
          ];
        
          for (const unit of timeUnits) {
            if (daysPassed < unit.duration * 30) {
              output = `${Math.floor(daysPassed / unit.duration)} ${unit.unit}${Math.floor(daysPassed / unit.duration) === 1 ? '' : 's'} ago`;
              break;
            }
        }
        }
```

Comment: Can you provide the (first) code block with its function wrapper? Surely this is not top-level code but a function body?

Answer (score 1):

Some elements that increase the cognitive complexity in your code:

- `if` statements. Each of them counts. Replacing with a single `for` loop can decrease this complexity.
- Sequences of operators (like `*`)
- Nested calls of functions

I believe a `for` loop should resolve the issue, but then you must get rid of the `if` statements. The loop condition can take that role.

I present the code as a function, as I assume that is your case:

```
function formatDelay(daysPassed) {
    const limits = [60, 24, 30, Infinity];
    const units = ["min", "hour", "day", "month"];
    let value = daysPassed;
    let i;
    for (i = 0; value >= limits[i]; i++) {
        value /= limits[i];
    }
    value = Math.floor(value);
    return `${value} ${units[i]}${value === 1 ? '' : 's'} ago`;
}
```

```js
function formatDelay(daysPassed) {
    const limits = [60, 24, 30, Infinity];
    const units = ["min", "hour", "day", "month"];
    let value = daysPassed;
    let i;
    for (i = 0; value >= limits[i]; i++) {
        value /= limits[i];
    }
    value = Math.floor(value);
    return `${value} ${units[i]}${value === 1 ? '' : 's'} ago`;
}

// Just some tests
for (let minutes of [15, 91, 60*10 + 10, 60*24*3 + 60, 60*24*30*8 + 100, 1000000000]) {
    console.log(formatDelay(minutes));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I write sometimes code as follows:

```
if (daysPassed < 60) {
    return `${Math.floor(daysPassed)} mins ago`;
}

if (daysPassed < 60 * 24) {
    return `${Math.floor(daysPassed / 60)} hours ago`;
}

..
```

Comment: for 4 conditions like mins ago, hours ago,  days ago, months ago sonarqube gives same error

Answer (score 0):

Doubtful this is an improvement over [@trincot's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76599276/636077) but it's sort of an interesting problem and I wanted to tinker with a solution.

```js
const units = [{
    name: 'min',
    numMinutes: 1,
  },
  {
    name: 'hour',
    numMinutes: 60,
  },
  {
    name: 'day',
    numMinutes: 60 * 24,
  },
  {
    name: 'month',
    numMinutes: 60 * 24 * 30
  }
];

function findUnit(numMinutes) {
  return units.find((item, index, arr) => {
      return item.numMinutes < numMinutes
      && (index === arr.length - 1 || arr[index + 1].numMinutes >= numMinutes);
  })
}

function formatOutput(numMinutes) {
  const unit = findUnit(numMinutes);
  const count = Math.floor(numMinutes / unit.numMinutes);
  return `${count} ${unit.name}${count === 1 ? '' : 's'} ago`;
}

[
  32, // 32 minutes
  183, // 3 hours
  60 * 24 * 3.2, // 3 days
  60 * 24 * 30 * 4.1, // 4 months
].forEach(value => {
  console.log(formatOutput(value));
})
```